# ShowAnchor formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, anchor

The formula below works well with just 1 item selection in google sheet under `showAnchor`.

I can select SALES ORDER. But what I want to do is to add another selection TRANSFER ORDER.

```js
function Test(){
  showAnchor('SALES ORDER','https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aYkNcR2o8Dh3zMXvOctd9XZNkeRziW5P-Ms7RHhjrx4/edit?usp=sharing');
}

function showAnchor(name,url) {
  var html = '<html><body><a href="'+url+'" target="blank" onclick="google.script.host.close()">'+name+'</a></body></html>';
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html)
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui,"ORDER PROFILE");
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking, could you please share more information about the sheet you're using and explain what it is you're trying  to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider this as just one way to meet your objective.

Based on your sample code, add a new function based on "Test". For example

```
function runTrans(){
showAnchor('TRANSFER ORDER','<<insert the url for your transfer order sheet>>');
}
```

Remember to insert the url of your Transfer Order into the code.

You can run:

- "Test" to open a "Sales Order Request spreadsheet" or
- "runTrans" to open a "Transfer Order spreadsheet"